# Adding a multirow between two mono-row entries of a row

Tags: tables, multirow

I have this table:

```
\documentclass[border = 2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        \toprule  
        \makecell{some long \\header} &B&1&2&3&C\\
        \bottomrule     
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which should become like:

[image]

I just tried this :

```
\documentclass[border = 2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        \toprule  
        \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{some long \\header} &B}&subtitle\\&1&2&3&C\\
        \bottomrule     
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

but to no avail.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this an option for you:

```
\documentclass[border = 2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

        \begin{tabular}{cclllc}
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{some long \\header}} & \multirow{2}{*}{B} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{subheader} & \multirow{2}{*}{C} \\ \cline{3-5}
            &                    & 1        & 2        & 3       &                    \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cclllc}
    \toprule
    \Block{2-1}{some long \\header} 
    & \Block{2-1}{B} 
    & \Block{1-3}{subheader} 
    &&& \Block{2-1}{C} \\ \cmidrule{3-5}
    & & 1 & 2 & 3 & \\ \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]